Cannot set Times New Roman font with mpdf 8.2.4 and greek chars
I am new with mpdf. I installed mpdf 8.2.4. No matter what I do, I can't get Times New Roman correctly with greek chars.
I have the following code:
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('pdf.html');

require_once DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
   'mode' => 'utf-8',
   'format' => 'A4',
   'default_font_size' => 16,
   'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
      DIR . '/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/roman',
   ]),
   'fontdata' => $fontData + [ // lowercase letters only in font key
     'roman' => [
        'R' => "timesnewroman.ttf",
        'B' => "timesnewroman-bold.ttf",
        'I' => "timesnewroman-italic.ttf",
       'BI' => "timesnewroman-bold-italic.ttf",
      ]
    ],
    'default_font' => 'roman'
]);
$mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', "url('images/border.png')");
$mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image-resize', 6);
$mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('margin-top', '10px');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','D');
?>

I have made a folder named roman in vendor/mpd/mpdf and put in there ttf files for Times New Roman with the exact names with R, B, I and BI. In my html file I have set in header:

I have also set:
body { font-family: roman; }
but tried also:
p { font-family: roman; }
with no success. I keep getting small squares instead of greek letters. Numbers and special chars are shown correctly though.
I tried, also, font-family: ctimes; with and without fontdir and fontdata with no success.  What am I doing wrong?
